# Does a reference singleton go on the stack or the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, singleton

I've read a lot of articles here about singletons, but none really touch my issue. I understand Singletons should only be use when needed and, in my game, I am using them for specific parts of the engine.

That said, I originally had my singletons as pointers like this:

```
static MapReader* Instance()
{
    if (instance == 0)
    {
        instance = new MapReader();
        return instance;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

However I always felt like using too many pointers is bad for leaks and I prefer not using them if I can help it (or smart pointers if I have to). So I've changed all my singletons to references like this:

```
static MapReader& Instance()
{
    static MapReader instance;
    return instance;
}
```

However, now I've notice my game to lag at odd times and then speed up, like the FPS are a little wonky.

My question is that; does the reference singleton all pile up on the stack? or do they still get allocated on the heap? And should I change them back to pointers using smart pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly not on the heap by virtue of the fact it's not created with `new`.

However, the standard is silent on *where* `static` variables are placed, mentioning only their *behaviour.* See for example, `C++11 3.7.1`:

> 1/ All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are not local have static storage duration. The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the program (3.6.2, 3.6.3).
>
> 2/ If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may be eliminated as specified in 12.8.
>
> 3/ The keyword static can be used to declare a local variable with static storage duration.
>
> 4/ The keyword static applied to a class data member in a class definition gives the data member static storage duration.

That's pretty much the extent of what the standard itself imposes on them.

Most implementations would likely have an area separate from both heap and stack for storing variables of static storage duration.

It's also almost certainly not the use of statics and references that are slowing your code down. Having looked deeply into compilers and how they work, statics tend to be at *least* as fast as other variables since they're very quick to locate in memory.

---

As an aside, your pointer variant of the singleton has two issues. The first is a potential race condition if you're working in a threaded environment. There's a possibility that more than one object may be created if distinct threads call `Instance()`.

Specifically, if thread A enters the `if` statement then thread B starts running, `B` can go through, create an object then return. If `A` then continues, it will create a *new* object.

If you're single-threaded, or you create the instance only from one thread, or you create the instance *before* other threads are running, you should be fine.

The second issue is just eye candy. There's no need to return the object from within the `if` block, since it will be returned when you get to the bottom of the function:

```
static MapReader* Instance() {
    if (instance == 0)
        instance = new MapReader();
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I'm worried it might slow down my code due to having too much on the stack. which is why I'm concerned to where the singletons are placed.

Comment: Too much stack won't slow down your code. It may crash it if you blow the size out but a reference is no more damaging than a pointer would be.

Comment: Well that's good to know that it wont slow things down and just crash. So far I haven't had any crash, just the odd FPS jump.

Comment: Well thank you! This sort of gives me an idea of the state of things and I will resume keeping them in as a reference. I would up-vote if I was allowed (need 15 rep)

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Static variables inside functions reside in the data section. For the record, so do static variables outside functions, and global ones.

Comment: I challenge you to find _one_ mention of a data section in the ISO standard :-)

Comment: And how's that relevant?

Comment: It's relevant because C++ has no concept of a data section. An _implementation_ may do it a certain way but that's not mandated. Technically, static storage duration variables _could_ be on the heap since a conforming implementation may `new` them all before `main()` is called.

Comment: Depends on what exactly the OP wants to know - the standard or the reality. :)

Comment: `objdump` or whatever platform equivalent can be used to verify that `static` is in fact stored in `.data`.

Comment: Seva, fair enough. They should probably mention the environment in that case since it may well differ greatly. I answered from just the C++ perspective because that's all they gave.

Comment: @Jason, my Misosys C compiler for the TRS80 Model III doesn't have an `objdump`. How can I verify where it is for that platform? :-) Sorry, just taking the mickey since you popped into the middle of a platform-specific/platform-agnostic discussion with a _very_ platform-specific suggestion.

Comment: I am mostly interested in the reality, as it is what will affect my game. However, I will agree with @paxdiablo that it could 'new' them when they are first created; which would be fine by me. I just don't want the stack to be full of static objects that use up memory and never go away.

Comment: Oria, they _could_ be on the stack. But, just as if they were on the heap, they'd be at the stack bottom where they'd stay for the duration. They wouldn't affect other stack operations at all othere than having them lower in memory (assuming your stack grows donward). In fact, even assuming your implementation _has_ a stack :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo The *reality* answer is very compiler/platform dependent though, since to the best of my knowledge it isn't specified in the standard.  Generally, if you're on a POSIX system, there should be an `objdump`.  I think there's dasm (32/64) for windows.  Sorry, I don't even know the executable format for the TRS80, let alone a disassembler :).

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah I would presume my implementation has a stack, doesn't all object not created on the heap with `new` go onto the stack? For platforms, this is currently being developed for both Windows and Linux, and using SDL2.

Comment: @Oria: While that's (mostly) possible, it's not usually done. The main reason is that these objects would need to be put at low positions on the stack so they don't go out of scope too early.